# How do I emit the value of an observable to an rxjs Subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'd like to provide an rxjs `Subject` from an Angular service to be able to emit values (via `next`) by calling methods on the service. One of the values I want it to emit is the result of an Angular `HttpClient` `get` call. I just can't seem to get it right. I am wondering why the following results in the subscribe handler not being called:

-View

```
export default abstract class TileView implements OnInit {
  constructor (private configService : ConfigService) {}
  ngOnInit () {
    this.configService.fetch(this.type()).subscribe( res => {
      console.log(res)
    }); 
  }
}
```

-Service

```
export class ConfigService {
  public subject = new AsyncSubject();

  constructor (private http : HttpClient) {}

  fetch (type) {
    this.http.get(
      api.host + api.base + interpolate(api.config, { type }) + "/"
    ).subscribe( res => {
      this.subject.next(res);
    });

    return this.subject;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to return the subject and also fire off the http call with a single method call? It's strange because the subject is returned, a subscriber is registered, the http call completes and `this.subject.next(res)` is called but the subscribe handler doesn't even run.

Comment: where are you subscribing to the subject?  You've created the 'next', but what is listening for it?

Comment: The subject is returned by the call to `fetch` from the View which I show there. The `subscribe` is happening there.

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully what you are trying to achieve.  If you are subscribing to fetch, it will return the results of your get.  Just call service.fetch wherever you want the results. Http.get constructs an observable.  https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Comment: That's what I'm saying is that it's not working. I'm subscribing to fetch and the subscriber never fires, even thought the http call is finishing successfully with data.

Comment: The http.get is already observable and can be subscribed to without a subject.  Simply return the res from your get subscription and you're done, I don't think you need a subscription like this: `fetch (type) {
    this.http.get(
      api.host + api.base + interpolate(api.config, { type }) + "/"
    ).subscribe( res => {
      return res
    });`

Comment: I only showed a small portion of my actual code. My intent is not just to have an http call, but also to be able for components to emit data on the subject through a method on the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pierre, the reason this happens is because **AsyncSubject only emits the last value when the observable *completes*** (determined by [`Subject.prototype.complete()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject#complete-)).

In your case, you'd likely want to use a BehaviorSubject, which emits the last value in the stream, for subscribers regardless of completion:

> An AsyncSubject emits the last value (and only the last value) emitted
>   by the source Observable, and only after that source Observable
>   completes. (If the source Observable does not emit any values, the
>   AsyncSubject also completes without emitting any values.)

[Subject Documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

Update:

If you are reluctant to use a BehaviorSubject because of the initial value propagation, use ReplaySubject(1).

Comment: Dang dude... But the reason I don't want to use BehaviorSubject is because it requires an initial value, and in my case I want the initial value to be the results of an http call.

Comment: You could use a ReplaySubject(1) :)

Comment: Simply swapping my `AsyncSubject` for a `ReplaySubject` caused the code to just start working like I wanted it to... :)

Comment: Awesome, buddy, glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

complete the observable and it will work

```
fetch (type) {
    this.http.get(
      api.host + api.base + interpolate(api.config, { type }) + "/"
    ).subscribe( res => {
      this.subject.next(res);
      this.subject.complete();
    });

    return this.subject;
  }
```

another approach is to use BehaviourSubject, in that case you need to handle null check as BehaviourSubject needs default value

```
public behaviourSub = new BehaviorSubject(null);

this.configService.fetch(this.type()).subscribe( res => {
    if (res !== null) {
      // actual value emitted
    }
});
```

Comment: You're right on point. I discovered I was missing the complete from @Rafael's answer above. I started with BehaviorSubject but then realized I needed an initial value when I construct it, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

One of the particularity of the AsyncObservable is that he wait the "**complete()**" to be done before sending the informations

It's not necessary since the AsyncSubject extend Observable, but I suggest you to use "**return this.subject.asObservable()**" which is part of the "Subject" object. Since you need to use it on other type of subject, if you change the type of you subject by **BehaviourSubject** for example you will not need to change your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the 'subject' in your view not to fetch. And no need to return the subject from your service also.

view:

```
export default abstract class TileView implements OnInit {
  constructor (private configService : ConfigService) {}
  ngOnInit () {
    this.configService.subjectChanged(this.type()).subscribe( res => {
      console.log(res)
    }); 
  }
}
```

Service:
export class ConfigService {

```
  public subjectChanged = new Subject();

  constructor (private http : HttpClient) {}

  fetch (type) {
    this.http.get(
      api.host + api.base + interpolate(api.config, { type }) + "/"
    ).subscribe( res => {
      this.subjectChanged.next(res);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason I was returning it from fetch, is because I wanted to trigger the http call and get a handle to the subject by calling a single method.

Comment: @Shahana With Pierre's approach, when any client code uses fetch(), all observers will get the propagated value, not just the caller (since they all subscribe to the *same* observable).

Comment: What happens if the service has also a post method (I mean, more methods)?